# Specifying output bin/tray when printing through javax.print

Tags: java, printing

Is there a way to choose which output bin/tray is used when printing in Java?  There is a an attribute MediaTray which allows you to pick the input tray, but I am unable to find one that allows you to choose output.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [MediaTray](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/attributes.fm5.html#1000214), there is a [Destination](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/attributes.fm5.html#997419) attribute in the Print Service API:

> The Destination attribute allows you to redirect your print data to a file rather than sending it to a printer device.

I hope it helps you.